# How to insert joomla user name inside an AJAX based article?

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I use joomla 3.x
I also use sourcerer plugin.

I have installed joomla in localhost at joomla30 directory.

I have my PHP & Ajax files in joomla30/cal directory.

I use sourcerer plugin and display php code.
From that php code I use ajax to call another PHP file at joomla30/cal directory.

So data is get from the php file inside the cal directory.
I need to get the user name from php code inside cal directory.

How to do that ?

I tried

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();
$user_id = $user->get('name');
```

but it didn work..

I get the error "Class JFactory not found."

Any other way to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't by default add PHP to a Joomla article. You must use a plugin such as [Sourcerer](http://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/sourcerer#download) to achieve this.

Once installed and enabled, simply use the following:

```
{source}
<?php
    jimport( 'joomla.user.user' ); // add this line in
    $user = JFactory::getUser();
    echo $user->name;
?>
{/source}
```

**Update:**

Seeing as you're using a custom php file, you will need to import the Joomla framework like so:

```
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );
define( 'JPATH_BASE', realpath(dirname(__FILE__).DS.'..' )); // change path accordingly

require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );

$mainframe = JFactory::getApplication('site');
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Im using this plugin and inserted by that only.

Comment: Nope.. Im using it in localhost.
It says Jfactory class not found.

Comment: That is really weird cause I have just tested this myself on my localhost and it works fine

Comment: Ahh I see now. You have an external PHP file. The code I provided in my answer, don't add it to your PHP file, simply add it to your article

Comment: I get this error `Call to undefined function jimport() in D:\xampp\htdocs\joomla30\cal\ajaxcal2.php`

Comment: Im passing the username to javascript to open a new pop up window.
So I need to use it in php file only.

Comment: My php file 1 is calling phpfile2 using ajax.
Whole code is there in phpfile 2 only.
php file 2 passes some variables to javascript. With that variables, i need this username also to be passed.

I have embedded php file 1 code using sourcerer in the article.

Comment: You will then need to import the Joomla framework in your custom php file. Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291233/connect-standalone-script-to-joomla-db-using-framework

Comment: Thanks bro... Its working good..
Pls add this as a seperate answer, so that I can mark it..

Comment: I've updated my current answer. Glad you got it working now :)